# Are assets affected by any game randomization logic?

Tags: payday-2

Let's say I buy the Nightclub Truck asset, which gives me a truck to pick up the cash, right behind the office where the vault is found, which helps a lot since the crew doesn't have to run the streets carrying the bags of cash.

Is there any randomization effect over this/all assets?

Let's say, in this case, the time for the truck to arrive.

Or if you buy a certain chopper to make your job easier, will the spot where arrives be the same every run or can it spawn somewhere else?

Comment: From what I've seen in the game, selecting each asset in the setup brings up a map that shows you where the asset will be.  I would think it's the same each time.

Comment: Ace Pilot from Day 3 of Rats, for instance, only shows a picture of a Heli Pilot smoking with a brown sexy mustache. Thats it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** This answer was written for an old version of the game (around update #15) and might not be accurate anymore.

**Some assets are, some are not** affected by random chance.

- Blueprints,
- insider info,
- keys,
- bag shortcuts,
- additional roof access,
- bad music,
- extra helicopter fuel,
- armored vehicle,
- floodlights,
- ammo and doctor bags and
- shutter codes

have no random elements to them, but

- Ace Pilot pickup location can change and
- camera access location can change.

(This list is probably far from complete)